# Calling external page with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to show in a `div` in an external HTML page?

Something like:

```
document.getElementById('pop_up_main').innerHTML = 'index.html';
```

Comment: use `iframe` and attach src to it

Comment: forgot to say: without using iframe. What is going to change is a webform (pop up).

Comment: Use HTML <object> Tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can, thats how ajax works.
just make sure you put that code in javascript and place it in a onload event.

```
function loadextPage()
{
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById('pop_up_main').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","index.html",true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
```

on your html body:

```
<body onload="loadextPage()">
```

Comment: it works perfect! I have just one question. The html page is bigger than the div from where get called. You think is best to adjust the div style or the content of html in the way that all fits right. To give you an idea I would give you the link in pvt with your permission

Comment: It depends, if your index.html is accessed somewhere by itself, I would say resize the div, if not you should resize the index.html
of course your best solution would be to resize the index so it shows correctly on both; the div and the html file by itself.